# outputs not generating in terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp, gcp-cloudsql

I have written a module for GCP CloudSQL in below path

`C:\new-softwares\terraform_1.2.9_windows_386\cloudsql\cloudsql-module`
and in this path i have below files

```
main.tf
variables.tf
outputs.tf
```

Above main.tf looks like

```
resource "google_sql_database_instance" "master1" {

    provider         = google-beta
    name             = var.name
```

and below is output.tf

```
output "master_instance_name" {
    description = "Name of the master database instance"
    value = google_sql_database_instance.master1.name
}
```

Then in the below path i am using this module to create Postgress instance

`C:\new-softwares\terraform_1.2.9_windows_386\cloudsql\my-posrgress` and it has files

```
locals.tf
main.tf
provider.tf
```

My terraform runs without any errors/warnings and resources are also created.
But no outputs are created even when i have defined outputs in the output.tf file,what i am missing here ?

Comment: What happens if you run `terraform output master_instance_name`?

Comment: Or `terraform show`? [link](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/commands/show)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You specified output in Child module and it is necessary to connect modules to each other. but in your case, so that the output is shown in the terminal, you have to put it to the Root module also:

```
# Create output.tf file in directory C:\new-softwares\terraform_1.2.9_windows_386\cloudsql\my-posrgress\outputs.tf and put:

output "master_instance_name" {
    description = "Name of the master database instance"
    value = module.<module_name>.master_instance_name
}
```